# Swapping current position with the highest value in an array

Tags: arrays, swap

I'm a bit new with the swapping topic and I'm stuck. I have to swap the current position with the position with the highest value within the array. This is my code currently.

```
void switchPlaces(string player[], int sum[], int numplayers) {
    int high = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numplayers; i++) {
        int current = sum[i];
        if (current > sum[high]) {
            high = i;
        }
        int hold = sum[i];
        sum[i] = high;
        high = hold;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to do? What do you mean by "current position"?

Comment: Ok so my code includes 6 players. The sum is basically the positions of the players. Let's say the array has the values {7, 14, 3, 18, 23, 5} and i'm at the value 3. How can i switch the 3 with the highest number, in this case, 23.

Comment: I'm still confused what you mean by "I'm at the value 3." The code you've written loops through all the values and tries to swap them all with the highest value, which makes no sense. First find the highest value, __then__ do a single swap.

Comment: OMG, i over thought that. Your last sentence got my mind back together. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help :)